# How to recall a Java method into JavaScript by Json?

Tags: javascript, java, html, json, jsp

I can't print a Json string, returning from a method Java in my html page. I can't recall the method 'proof' Java in JavaScript. Can you give me some hints?

**Java class**

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class JsonDiProva {

public String proof() {

    List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    names.add("Alice");
    names.add("Bob");
    names.add("Carol");
    names.add("Mallory");

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String jsonNames = gson.toJson(names);

    return jsonNames;

    }
}
```

---

**Jsp page**

```
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
var prv = JSON.parse('<% new JsonDiProva().proof() %>;');
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = prv; 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Your `;` after the `%>` makes the JSON invalid, here:

```
var prv = JSON.parse('<% new JsonDiProva().proof() %>;');
```

That's because your `proof` method presumably returns something like `["a","b","c"]`, so it will try to do `JSON.parse('["a","b","c"];')`, notice the semicolon - which will fail because `["a","b","c"];` *with semicolon* is not valid JSON syntax.

It should look like this:

```
var prv = JSON.parse('<% new JsonDiProva().proof() %>');
```

But this looks like a weird way to do it anyway, I'd just write it like this:

```
var prv = <% new JsonDiProva().proof() %>;
```

This works because the result will be like `var prv = ["a","b","c"];` which is exactly what we want, no extra parsing needed.

2) You are assigning what is probably an array to `innerHTML`. I think this won't work the way you expected.

Firstly, you should use `innerText` and not `innerHTML` unless you really want to display HTML in there. Secondly, your array will be implicitely converted to a string which will look like `a,b,c`, without spaces there. You should probably call `join` to make it look nicer, like this:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = prv.join(", ");
```

Note the extra space after the comma, so it will afterwards be displayed as `a, b, c`.

(The other advantage here is that you could otherwise mistakenly believe that `prv` is a string and call something like `replace` on it and wonder why it won't work.)

Comment: It can't print it yet. I tryed your hints unsuccessfully.